# how to print only date and not include the time in datetime.datetime.strptime()

Tags: python, datetime

I have this code :

```
>>> import datetime
>>> l = '2011-12-02'
>>> t = datetime.datetime.strptime(l, '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> print t
2011-12-02 00:00:00
```

my question is, it is possible that only the `2011-12-02` will be printed?

Comment: btw, you're really looking for how to get a formatted string from an instance of `datetime`.  The `strptime` function merely takes a string and gives you a new instance of `datetime`.  Understanding this difference will help you work through things like this in the future.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
>>> t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2011-12-02'
```

Comment: is there any way that it will not become a string?

Comment: @gadss your question is self-contradicting. You either want it as a proper date-time object, or as a string. There's no other format.

Answer (score 7):

With [`strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
print t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: `time.strftime` is actually format first, time second, and the time is in fact not a `datetime` (which our OP has), but a `struct_time`.  He should use the `strftime` in the `datetime` module.

Comment: I edited my answer a *loong* time ago. The code works, as I tested it before answering. If you're confused about the link, sorry. I used it as an example of the syntax, not the actual function...

Comment: The code you initially wrote definitely didn't work, and you can blame SO's apparent eventual-consistency model for why my view of your answer never updated while I could see your new comments.

Comment: Oh well. I went through three revisions before un-deleting my answer, so darn you latency!

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the output format for the date, e.g. by using

```
print t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

All the letter after a "%" represent a format: %d is the day number, %m is the month number, %y is the year last two digits, %Y is the all year

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use like this

```
 d = datetime.datetime(2011,7,4)
 print '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(d)
```

or your code:

```
import datetime
l = '2011-12-02'
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(l, '%Y-%m-%d')
print '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and easiest way is to use the method function `.date()`

```
l = '2011-12-02'
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(l, '%Y-%m-%d')

print(t.date())
```

You get:

```
2011-12-02
```

More generally:

If you have some datetime like this `datetime.datetime.now()` you can simply add `.date()` at the end:

```
print(datetime.datetime.now().date())
```

Which gives:

```
2023-07-04
```

This is what I personally prefer over the solutions of `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` and `print '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(d)` which also indeed work perfectly well.